# Use iPod Touch bluetooth to connect mobile phone and use dial-up for internet

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, bluetooth

Is it possible to code a program which connects to my phone and use its dial-up service (GRPS/EDGE) to connect to the Internet?

Comment: Isn't this more of a StackOverflow question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the app iBluever which seems to be able to do this job.
Thanks anyway.